# open ball on metric $d''(z,z') = \max \{d_i(x_i,x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

I have the following metric:

$d''(z,z') = \max \{d_i(x_i,x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

What figures form the open and closed ball? What about the sphere?

That's what I thought:

[image]

Open ball should be the square without is edge. Closed ball should be the edge. The last one is the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) has a nice picture of spheres in the $l^p$ norms (ignore values of $p<1$):

[image]

Your norm is the last one, $l^{\infty}$.